# Reload webView widget automaticly with a loop and a timer

Tags: python, pyqt5, plotly, qthread, qwebview

I'm creating a GUI where I want to display a site with qWebView and reload it automaticly every 10 seconds.

I tried with a qThread, no results. (I'm a new with threading)
And if I use a normal while loop my window freeze.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class updator(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, window):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)


    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.sleep(2000 * 2 / 1000)
            self.window.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph.reload()

class Ui_BTC_LiveGraph(object):
    def setupUi(self, BTC_LiveGraph):
        BTC_LiveGraph.setObjectName("BTC_LiveGraph")
        BTC_LiveGraph.resize(1600, 900)
        BTC_LiveGraph.setAccessibleDescription("")
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(
            BTC_LiveGraph)
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1500, 800))
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph.setAccessibleDescription("")
        # récupération du chemin absolu du fichier
        self.mypath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(
            str("file:///" + self.mypath + "/BTC_liveGraph.html")))
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph.setObjectName("htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph")

        self.retranslateUi(BTC_LiveGraph)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(BTC_LiveGraph)

    def retranslateUi(self, BTC_LiveGraph):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        BTC_LiveGraph.setWindowTitle(
            _translate("BTC_LiveGraph", "BTC Live Graph"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    BTC_LiveGraph = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_BTC_LiveGraph()
    ui.setupUi(BTC_LiveGraph)
    BTC_LiveGraph.show()
    update = updator(ui)
    update.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would like the qwebviewWidget to reload every 10 seconds smouthly and having no freeze for the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `QTimer` is a better way to tackle this problem, here is a working example:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QRect, QUrl, QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class Ui_BTC_LiveGraph(object):
    def setupUi(self, widget):
        widget.setObjectName("BTC_LiveGraph")
        widget.resize(1600, 900)
        widget.setAccessibleDescription("")
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph = QWebEngineView(widget)
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 1500, 800))
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph.setAccessibleDescription("")
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph.setObjectName("htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph")

        self.retranslateUi(widget)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, widget):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("BTC_LiveGraph", "BTC Live Graph"))


class MainWindow(Ui_BTC_LiveGraph, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        # You can do this here, just keep the Ui class for UI stuff
        self.mypath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph.setUrl(QUrl('http://www.stackoverflow.com'))

        self._updator = QTimer(self)
        self._updator.setSingleShot(False)
        self._updator.timeout.connect(self.reload)
        # Reload every 4 seconds
        self._updator.start(4000)

    def reload(self):
        self.htmlreader_BTCLiveGraph.reload()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    BTC_LiveGraph = MainWindow()
    BTC_LiveGraph.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for being so fast!!!!!!!!